`pnpm install`: "ERROR This project is configured to use ^pnpm"
I have forked an open source project that uses pnpm. I am using Windows with Node 18.
I have installed pnpm using npm install -g pnpm as per https://pnpm.io/installation#using-npm
In the project directory, I ran pnpm install and it fails with the following error:
$ pnpm install
 ERROR  This project is configured to use ^pnpm
For help, run: pnpm help install

There is no "packageManager" field in the package.json file. If I add one with value pnpm, I still see the same error.
How can I fix this? The project won't install properly with npm, so I think I need to use pnpm.
Here is a detailed repro log:
# I'm using "Git Bash" on Windows
$ uname -a
MINGW64_NT-10.0-22631 my-machine 3.4.7-25de8b84.x86_64 2023-08-28 21:32 UTC x86_64 Msys

$ node --version
v18.20.4

$ npm install -g pnpm
...

$ pnpm --version
9.12.3

$ git clone git@github.com:astahmer/openapi-zod-client.git
Cloning into 'openapi-zod-client'...

$ cd openapi-zod-client/lib/

$ pnpm install
 ERROR  This project is configured to use ^pnpm
For help, run: pnpm help install

$ pnpm --version
 ERROR  This project is configured to use ^pnpm
For help, run: pnpm help



Which pnpm version? Please, provide additional data, at least package.json. If this is open source project, please, refer it. "The project won't install properly with npm" - is there a reason for this?

@EstusFlask -- I have added more info on versions and a repro log. The package.json is at https://github.com/astahmer/openapi-zod-client/blob/main/lib/package.json

This seems to be a (not so new) bug: https://github.com/astahmer/openapi-zod-client/issues/295 (the "^" exists in workspace root) - maybe it's the corepack version?!

Thanks, yes, @JeffRSon -- looks like the dir above has "^" in it?? https://github.com/astahmer/openapi-zod-client/blob/76d86f66332a86742bed192689281f6da96d3305/package.json#L18   How come this works at all for the authors of openapi-zod-client? If you convert your comment to an answer, I'll accept it

The "^pnpm" comes from the package.json in workspace root of the repository (https://github.com/astahmer/openapi-zod-client/blob/main/package.json#L18)
There seems to be a misunderstanding about the format of the "packageManager" entry in package.json.
Current pnpm (9.12.3) reports the error:

ERROR  This project is configured to use ^pnpm

It seems it started with pnpm 9.7.0. That's probably why it works for developers of openapi-zod-client (9.7.0 is about 3 months old: https://www.npmjs.com/package/pnpm?activeTab=versions)
BTW, corepack reports a similar error:

UsageError: Unsupported package manager specification (^pnpm@8.2.0)

"packageManager" entry is documented in https://nodejs.org/api/packages.html#packagemanager as <package manager name>@<version>. Such, if you need to work with the repository, just remove "^" in https://github.com/astahmer/openapi-zod-client/blob/main/package.json

This should be the accepted answer. The package manager field does not support regex
